# How can I make an android layout with four quadrants and a circle in between

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to design a layout with four divided columns and a circle in the center something like the image in the link below. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to design the columns and circle is a single png, and then just show it as a background of the layout and the place the TextView in the desired order of your choosing , and as for the center textView put it inside a Constraint Layout and then center it.

[image]

This is how you want it to be, and it can be done like this

[image]

You can easily these in Photoshop or whatever tool suits you
On and yess keep in mind that i just moved the column 1px outwards in the respective way so as to create that central divider look since adding individual border to each columns inward side would be more hectic, and this way you just have to move the columns outward (if you move then up remember to move them to left/right respectively or if you move them bottom do the same and move the left/right so as to have them in perfect sync.

**Another Method**

Another method would be to us each piece of this design individually and them use them as the backgrounds for each TextView or have them as the background for each RelativeLayout 's background and have them as Parent to each TextView.

And As For the Image of the Jersey You place it dynamically in the Relativelayout of the inner Circle.

I hope this helps.